# Giving an onclick function to a link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick

I'm messing around with JavaScript and I want to have a coloured square with 3 links and depending on the link I click, the square will change colours. I can't get it to work and I'm not sure where I went wrong..

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page 2</title>
    <script src="switch.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='square' src="img/blue.png"><br>
    <a href="#" id='blue'>Blue!</a>
    <a href='#' id='red'>Red!</a>
    <a href='#' id='green'>Green!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

switch.js

```
var switch = (function() {
    var red = document.body.getElementById('red');
    var square = document.body.getElementById('square');
    red.onclick = function() {
        square.src = 'img/red.png';
    }
})();
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('red')` and `document.getElementById('square');`

Comment: Don't use `switch` as a variable name, that is a token used my javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues.

First you are using a variable called `switch`, that is a no no. Switch is a reserved word because it is a switch statement. Rename it.

```
var xswitch = (function() {
```

Second, It is because you are runnnig the code before the element exists on the page. It needs to be executed onload, document dom loaded [ready], or the script needs to be added at the bottom of the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='square' src="img/blue.png"><br>
    <a href="#" id='blue'>Blue!</a>
    <a href='#' id='red'>Red!</a>
    <a href='#' id='green'>Green!</a>
    <script src="switch.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running your code before the elements exist.

Move the `<script>` element to the bottom of the `<body>` (so that it runs after they exist), or run the code in the load event.

Comment: Moved the <script> still doesn't work. What do you mean by load event?

Comment: It was the reserved word... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes in order to ensure that the DOM has loaded.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page 2</title>
    <script src="switch.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            switchFn();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='square' src="img/blue.png"><br>
    <a href="#" id='blue'>Blue!</a>
    <a href='#' id='red'>Red!</a>
    <a href='#' id='green'>Green!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (switch.js)

```
var switchFn = function () {
    var red = document.getElementById('red');
    var square = document.getElementById('square');
    red.onclick = function () {
        square.src = 'img/red.png';
    }
};
```